# When and why does List remove(Object object) return false

Tags: java, list

When and why does the method `boolean java.util.List.remove(Object object)` return false?

The documentation states

> [The method returns] true if this List was modified by this operation,
>   false otherwise.

Why wouldn't the operation take effect on the List?

(NB: The implementation of the List I am making use of is the `ArrayList`)

**Update:**
The objects I am trying to remove do exist in the List. I add the class to the `List` (hence the argument `this`) and pass `this` (within the same class) to the remove method. Therefor the object should exist in the List (or not?).

**Update:**
Here is the code. Have a look at the `delay()` method. There is where I attempt to remove the respective class from the `List`.

```
public class Timer extends Object {

    private static List<Timer> allTimers;
    private Long startTime;
    private int delayTime;
    private boolean registered;

    String name;

    public Timer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.registered = true;
        allTimers.add(this);
        Log.d("SpaceDroid", "Foo: Created timer: " + name + " Size: " + this.allTimers.size());

    }

    public Timer(String name, int delayTime) {
        this(name);
        this.delayTime = delayTime;

    }

    public void setDelayTime(int delayTime) {
        this.delayTime = delayTime;

    }

    public boolean delay() {
        if(this.startTime == null) {
            this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        if(startTime + this.delayTime < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            if(this.registered) {
                Log.d("SpaceDroid", "Foo: Trying to remove timer: " + name);
                if(this.allTimers.remove(this)) {
                    Log.d("SpaceDroid", "Foo: Successfully removed timer: " + name);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("SpaceDroid", "Foo: Did not remove timer: " + name);
                }

            }
            return true;

        }
        else {
            return false;

        }

    }

    // The same as resume, just renew the startTime

    public void reset() {
        this.startTime = null;
        this.registered = true;
        this.allTimers.add(this);

    }

    public void resume() {
        this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

    public void pause() {
        // Check if timer is still running
        if(!this.delay()) {
            // Calculate new delayTime
            delayTime = (int) ((startTime + this.delayTime) - System.currentTimeMillis());
            Log.d("SpaceDroid", "Foo: New delay time: " + delayTime + " for timer: " + name);

        }


    }

    public static void resumeAllTimers() {
        List<Timer> timers = new ArrayList<Timer>(Timer.allTimers);
        for (Timer timer : timers) {
            timer.resume();
        }

    }

    public static void pauseAllTimers() {
        List<Timer> timers = new ArrayList<Timer>(Timer.allTimers);
        for (Timer timer : timers) {
            timer.pause();
        }

    }

    public static void disposeAllTimers() {
        Timer.allTimers.clear();
        Timer.allTimers = null;

    }

    public static void initializeAllTimers() {
        allTimers = new ArrayList<Timer>();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 12):

If the `Object` passed in is not actually in the list, it wouldn't take any effect on the list and therefore return false.

Edit (thanks Jai):
The method uses the specific `Object`s `equals()` method to determine if it contains that object. So, if you have custom objects make sure you override the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method, and also the [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) (to maintain the general contract between the methods).

Comment: Also if you are using custom objects in List.Make sure you have overridden hashcode and equals method.

Answer (score 2):

Since List is an interface, it wouldn't have a concrete implementation for an example. But taking from ArrayList, it will return **false** if:

- you pass null and there's no null object in the list, or
- you pass an object not found on the list

**From ArrayList.java**

```
     public boolean remove(Object o) {
         if (o == null) {
             for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
                 if (elementData[index] == null) {
                     fastRemove(index);
                     return true;
                 }
         } else {
             for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
                 if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
                     fastRemove(index);
                     return true;
                 }
         }
         return false;
     }
```

Adding the code of fastRemove, for completeness:

```
 private void fastRemove(int index) {
      modCount++;
      int numMoved = size - index - 1;
      if (numMoved > 0)
          System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                           numMoved);
      elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc do its work
  }
```

Proving it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("Removing null on empty list: " + l.remove(null));
        System.out.println("Removing an object that won't be found: " + l.remove(new Object()));
}
```

Result:

```
Removing null on empty list: false
Removing an object that won't be found: false
```

Answer (score 1):

from this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
>   if it is present (optional operation). If this list does not contain
>   the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with
>   the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null :
>   o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists). Returns true if this
>   list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list
>   changed as a result of the call).