# Optimizing the ArrayList Condition

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization, arraylist

I  have some values in my Array list and I have to remove some particular values based on conditions.I am using IF condition but there are many conditions to compare so I need to optimize the comparison time.for e.g. my list is

> Msisdn_array={45,85,79,60,502}

and if condition match then remove the entry.

Below are the Conditions, Is there any possible way to optimize this conditions.

```
if(Msisdn_array.contains("60") && Msisdn_array.contains("910"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("60");
Msisdn_array.remove("910");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("75") && Msisdn_array.contains("500"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("75");
Msisdn_array.remove("500");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("76") && Msisdn_array.contains("502"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("76");
Msisdn_array.remove("502");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("61") && Msisdn_array.contains("911"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("61");
Msisdn_array.remove("911");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("77") && Msisdn_array.contains("503"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("77");
Msisdn_array.remove("503");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("78") && Msisdn_array.contains("505"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("78");
Msisdn_array.remove("505");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("79") && Msisdn_array.contains("507"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("79");
Msisdn_array.remove("507");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("62") && Msisdn_array.contains("912"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("62");
Msisdn_array.remove("912");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("63") && Msisdn_array.contains("913"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("63");
Msisdn_array.remove("913");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("64") && Msisdn_array.contains("914"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("64");
Msisdn_array.remove("914");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("65") && Msisdn_array.contains("915"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("65");
Msisdn_array.remove("915");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("66") && Msisdn_array.contains("916"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("66");
Msisdn_array.remove("916");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("67") && Msisdn_array.contains("917"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("67");
Msisdn_array.remove("917");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("68") && Msisdn_array.contains("918"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("68");
Msisdn_array.remove("918");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("69") && Msisdn_array.contains("919"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("69");
Msisdn_array.remove("919");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("70") && Msisdn_array.contains("920"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("70");
Msisdn_array.remove("920");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("71") && Msisdn_array.contains("921"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("71");
Msisdn_array.remove("921");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("72") && Msisdn_array.contains("922"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("72");
Msisdn_array.remove("922");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("73") && Msisdn_array.contains("923"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("73");
Msisdn_array.remove("923");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("74") && Msisdn_array.contains("924"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("74");
Msisdn_array.remove("924");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("80") && Msisdn_array.contains("926"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("80");
Msisdn_array.remove("926");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("81") && Msisdn_array.contains("927"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("81");
Msisdn_array.remove("927");
}

if(Msisdn_array.contains("82") && Msisdn_array.contains("928"))
{
Msisdn_array.remove("82");
Msisdn_array.remove("928");
}
```

Comment: It seems OP needs to check if two elements exist, and if they do, then remove them both, otherwise do nothing. So just calling remove is not going to give the desired result in the case that only one of the elements exists.

Comment: create a method `removeBoth (String one, String two)` and perform generic logic.  This will be easier to read and debug than any optimized code

Answer (score 1):

One potential optimization is that you could don't need to check if the second item is in the list. Instead just attempt to remove it. If it was removed, the `remove` method [will return true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16120404/4297364) and you can also remove the first item.

```
if(Msisdn_array.contains("60") && Msisdn_array.remove("910")){
    Msisdn_array.remove("60");
}
```

If you don't want to write out each if statement, you could store the groups in a Map, with the first item as the key and the second item as the value.

```
Map<String, String> rules = new HashMap<>();
rules.put("60", "910");
rules.put("75", "500");
rules.put("76", "502");
...
...
for(Entry entry : rules.values()) {
    if(Msisdn_array.contains(entry.getKey()) && Msisdn_array.remove(entry.getValue())){
        Msisdn_array.remove(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to extract a method to check if all of a group values are existed in List and then remove all. For example:

```
    private void removeIfAllExist(List<String> list, String[] values) {
    for (String v : values) {
        if (!list.contains(v)) {
            return;
        }
    }
    list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(values));
}

public void yourLogic() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("45", "85", "79", "60", "502"));
    String[][] conditions = new String[][]{
            new String[]{"60", "910"},
            new String[]{"75", "500"},
            new String[]{"76", "502"},
            new String[]{"61", "911"},
            new String[]{"77", "503"},
            // more conditions
    };
    for (String[] values : conditions) {
        removeIfAllExist(list, values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not iterate through the list often, I suggest you use a Set.
Search in this collection is fast.

Answer (score 0):

`contains` is an O(n) operation. The list is traversed until the element is found. So every time you call `contains` you are potentially traversing the entire list.

An optimization might be to traverse the list once, manually, and check if the elements exist, and then do your removes afterwards, at the cost of some extra memory to store the boolean variables:

```
boolean exists_72 = false;
boolean exists_922 = false;

for(String element : Msisdn_array) {
    if(element.equals("72")) {
        exists_72 = true;
    } else if(element.equals("922")) {
        exists_922 = true;
    }
}

if(exists_72 && exists_922) }
    Msisdn_array.remove("72");
    Msisdn_array.remove("922");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as remove returns a boolean is sucessfully removed you could do

```
if (list.remove ("60") && list.remove ("90"))
{
   // everything ok
}
else {
  // put back "60"
  list.add ("60");
}
```

**but** personally I would go for readability a just create a method

```
removeBoth (String one, String two) {
  if(list.contains(one) && list.contains(two))
  {
     list.remove(one);
     list.remove(two);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's slow because of `List.contains` being slow and also because `List.remove` being even slower (as it must move all elements with bigger indexes in order to fill the gap). It's ugly because of code repetition.

`Msisdn_array` is against Java naming convention and it's no array, so lets call it `inputList`. Let's use a `HashSet` for the lookups and another one to track what should be removed.

```
class Worker {
    private final Set<String> inputListAsSet = new HashSet<>();
    private final Set<String> removals = new HashSet<>();

    public static void process(List<String> inputList) {
        final Worker worker = new Worker(inputList);
        worker.removeIfBothPresent("60", "910");
        worker.removeIfBothPresent("75", "500");
        worker.removeIfBothPresent("76", "502");
        worker.removeIfBothPresent("61", "911");
        worker.removeIfBothPresent("72", "922");
        worker.removeIfBothPresent("73", "923");
        worker.removeIfBothPresent("74", "924");
        worker.removeIfBothPresent("80", "926");
        worker.removeIfBothPresent("81", "927");
        worker.removeIfBothPresent("82", "928");
        inputList.removeAll(worker.removals);
    }

    private Worker(List<String> inputList) {
        inputListAsSet.addAll(inputList);
    }

    private void removeIfBothPresent(String first, String second) {
        if (inputListAsSet.contains(first) && inputListAsSet.contains(second)) {
            removals.add(first);
            removals.add(second);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using a class instance, the sets could be passed as arguments, but creating a worker seems cleaner. Note that despite the optimizations, my code is shorter than the original. In case of duplicates, it's not exactly equivalent.